# javascript/AJAX template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have recently taken over a project, and there is one thing i don't get about it. 
Somehow there is a .js file that can change the names and values of the variables and such by using the @ symbol. this is somehow called via the window object, for example i have one of the .js files with some ajax call in it:

```
var values@TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID;
var regtemp@TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID = @REGISTRATION_TEMPLATE_ID;

function save@TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID(){
    if (isRegistration@TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID){
        SaveInput@TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID();
        var toGoValues = ConvertRegistrationToGoValues@TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/SaveStandard.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'arrvalues': toGoValues, 'regID': registrationID@TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID},
            cache: false,
            success: function(json) {
            ImSaved();
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }
    });
}
    else{
        values@TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID = new Array();

        SaveInput@TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID();
        AddToGoArray@TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/SaveStandard.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'arrvalues': values@TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID, 'regID': 1},
            cache: false,
            success: function(json) {
            ImSaved();
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is somehow called with `window[value]();` where value could hold something like 1084. 1084 is entered where it says @TEMPLATE_CONTROL_ID.

My Question is does anyone recognise this, i figure that there should be some kind of map or something but i need to call something else, and would love to know how this works.

Comment: Seems like the JS file itself is a template. Which seems awful since you could solve this with plain old code, at least AFAICT. There's probably something in your system that pre-processes this.

Comment: That's the exact conclusion i've reached, however i have found nothing to prove this, which is why i would love to know the name of this so that i may read up on it.

Comment: You'll need to dig into your system to see how the interpolated files are served, which will probably lead you to how/why it happens. It's also possible it's a template used "statically", e.g., there's a utility that generates the interpolated files. Without knowing more it'll be tough to provide much more, unless someone recognizes the specific syntax.